# Redirect Restful directly to Couchbase to reduce encoding decoding

Tags: java, php, android, couchbase, redirect

Could any one of you suggest what would be the proper solution to this design.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish and I'm not sure whether it's all possible.

Infrastructure

Android > Php ZF > Couchbase

So all communication is done using Restful.  Currently how it works in my apps is as follow.  Android requesting an image file say jpg/png to my apps via Restful.  Myapps needs image file stored in the Couchbase so it contacted Couchbase via Restful, received file in apps server, decode the restful from base64 back to jpg/png , Encode the data again to base64/Json, transfer it to Android device.  Android device received the Json in base64, decode it back to the jpg/png.

Does this movement make sense?

So in order to cut down on decoding>encoding>decoding.  I'm wondering whether it's possible for me to have my android contact the Couchbase directly via my PhpZF apps server and just do decoding once after it arrived at the android device?

Please advise?  Many thanks everyone.  Hope this make sense on what I'm asking for?

Comment: Have you seen sync-gateway project? https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway

Comment: Thanks for the reference avsej.  That's something I'll need to do in the future product update.  But for now, I don't think that project pertain to this question though.  All I'm asking is whether it's possible for me to let android query directly to couchbase without giving them direct access to couchbase.  Thus the apps server as the re-router or something.